# How can I move the cursor to the end of the text (Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, focus, sendmessage, text-cursor

This is my code to fill a TextBox using the `SendMessage` function:

```
  C := 'Hey there';
  SendMessage(h1, WM_SETTEXT, 1, Integer(PChar(C)));
```

Now, how can I move the cursor to the end of the text?

Comment: Ouch! Not very Delphi-ish. I presume the TextBox is **not** a Delphi component?

Comment: The SendMessage function is an API and there is no rule to using windows APIs for our project only . for example we use this function to fill the yahoo messenger Textbox , Editbox , Box , Field . totally : "TextBox" is a virtual box on computer that we type on it using keyboard !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you really want to do this with messages take a look at:

1. [EM_SETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761661%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
2. [EM_EXSETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788007%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Also there you have the complete reference for edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485923%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

In code (no messages) you would do something like this:

```
Edit1.SelLength := 0;
Edit1.SelStart := 0;   // set caret before first character
...
Edit1.SelStart := 1;   // set caret before second character
...
Edit1.SelStart := Length(Edit1.Text) // set caret after the last character
```

With messages:

```
SendMessage(h1, EM_SETSEL, Length(C), Length(C));
```

Comment: Thank you Runner . but the box is not for my project ! i want to do this with an external application .

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is wrong . you have to using "EM_SETSEL" parameter . my problem solved with this code :

```
  //Set a value for external textbox
  SendMessage(h1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Integer(PChar(C)));
  //move the cursor to end of the textbox(editbox,field,...)
  SendMessage(h1, EM_SETSEL, length(C), length(C));
```

Thank you , anyway :)

Comment: sorry forgot to change the message constant. I posted the correct links though. Thanks for pointing out, I will fix it right away.